# Firefox vs Chrome/IE layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

First question in the community and excited to have found a place with so much knowledge!

My website, http://www.localcookingclasses.com, displays slightly differently on Firefox vs Chrome and IE. The gray background shows on Firefox, while Chrome and IE display the entire site in white.

What could trigger this? I think it might be a missing closed  but I haven't found it.

Is there a particular file or line of code I can share with you, or can enough info be pulled from the URL I provided? I want to make sure I include enough information.

Attaching screenshot of Firefox which shows the gray background.

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjuov.jpg)

Comment: Looks the same to me. You have some syntax errors though. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.localcookingclasses.com%2F

Comment: Can you please attach screenshots of what you see in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: chrome top left, firefox top right, safari bottom http://i.imgur.com/rjEssGo.png

Comment: Interesting, I'm not seeing the same even after clearing cache. Anyone else able to confirm?

Answer (score -1):

Just opened them on Firefox and Chrome and they look exactly the same to me.

Maybe refresh the cache?

Also there are some css atributes that are specific of chrome and firefox, if you could share the background snipet of the css I could be able to help.

EDIT: Screenshots of what I see (requested by user)
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOSz6.png)-----[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsYji.jpg)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Can you please attach screenshots of what you see in Firefox and Chrome?